# Sending notification to a particular user or a particular channel in android using PHP

Tags: java, android, android-studio

i have been working on an APP where people registers and then subscribes for some kind of specific notifications i have created the APP already (pretty much done)

i am new to the APP develelopment and have less knowledge about JAVA so if i am wrong anytime please do let me know thankx

**What i have now**
**user can login or signup etc and when signup i create a notification chanel with his/her phone number**

NOTIFICATION CODE

```
private void createNotificationChannel() {
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
            CharSequence name = channel_name;
            String description = channel_description;
            int importance = NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_DEFAULT;
            NotificationChannel channel = new NotificationChannel("124t", name, importance);
            channel.setDescription(description);
            NotificationManager notificationManager = getSystemService(NotificationManager.class);
            notificationManager.createNotificationChannel(channel);
        }
    }
```

now i have no idea what to do after this how do i check the notification channels created and send test  notification using some kind of API etc.

any reference or answer is appreciated.

Thankx

Comment: Do you want to send notifications to the user from your app? maybe a background process? Or you are trying to implement notifications from backend where you send a notification to a specific user from your server?

Comment: from the server is my requirement, @BogdanAndroid

Comment: Ok then, what you did is just to send notifications from your app to the user, that great, but now you have to implement a backend with a DB like mysql and a php webservice for example wich you have to call from a background process of your app each X time.

Then, when your php webservice retrieve the data from the mysql (the data is the content of your notification). You can send it to the user across the NotificationManager. 
This process is long to implement and not really the best way, too much backend calls from your clients... Instead, I recomend you to use Firebase Cloud Messaging!

Comment: Thank you so much for the reply @BogdanAndroid really appreciate it. why i want to use my mysql server to send notification is. i already have the website and APP with sql server / database and notification content ready. as of now we push SMS insted of push notification. so i think it may be long process but i have already more than half way. 

i would really appreciate if you can guide me how to send the NOTIFICATION from PHP mysql server. Thankx

Comment: You are welcome, the thing is that you can't SEND it from php to your app, what you can do is check periodically your php webservice from your app, but as I said it is not a good practice since you will make too much http calls when mostly times the user will have not any notifications...

Comment: ok i do understand you, i also have basic knowledge with Firebase, but what the current system is doing is, when some one sends a message to any user we insert the data into MYSQL database and then we add the SMS API, is that not possible to insert any API or something there only and we send the data to APP user, i dont mind any database / Firebase or etc. i dont want to do too many HTTP requests... @BogdanAndroid and you are awesome.

Comment: Hi there, I would suggest you use Firebase and send the push notification with Firebase Cloud Messagin. The SMS way looks very expensive to me.

Take a look at this documentation: https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/send-message#java